# Android drawable for Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 12.2 SM-T900

Tags: android, drawable, tablet, screen-resolution

We are designing the application for Tablet, I have made the draw-able folder for **7 and 10 inch Tablet** but as we can see that also some Android device is available in market which size is **2560 x 1600 pixels, 12.2 inches**.

Can you please ensure which draw-able folder will be used in **12.2 inch Tablet**.

Recently released new **Samsung Tab PRO 12.2** in market

Thanks

Comment: Make all your `drawables` a vector one so you need not to worry about size variations.

Comment: i think drawable-sw1600dp its works.

Answer (score 0):

Im using this method to find out what layout folder will be selected for each device.

at first add one view on ur starting Layout in each folder.

for example in "layout-land-xxhdpi"  folder in Activity_main.xml file:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0.0dip"
    android:layout_height="0.0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
    android:id="@+id/layouttype"
    android:tag="layout-land-xxhdpi"/>
```

or in "layout-xlarge" folder in Activity_main.xml file:

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        android:id="@+id/layouttype"
        android:tag="layout-xlarge"/>
```

then inside use below code to find out what folder are getting selected for ur device.

the layout name and folder will be apear in logcat.

```
    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.layouttype);
       Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Layout is : "+ v.getTag().toString());
```

im making all standrad layout folders for my application since its going to run all device.
with above method i designed all layout i want per each device.

Comment: Thanks for giving response I have already got this idea but while we are create the application geting some draw-able folder but for the tablet we have to make separate layout such as I am using for 7 and 10 inch tablet draw-able folder drawable-large-hdpi and drawable-large-mdpi.

Comment: this is exactly what im doing for my application , i have about 34 different device with different dimension size. and since our team are developing in global mode we made near about 140 unique layout for each device type :D we support all tablet dimension too since its a news reader like newsrepublic